# How to find any cells in a Google Spreadsheet that are coloured red?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that uses only black font. I have already added an onEdit script that will colour the font red of any cell that is edited.

What I would like to do is determine whether there are any cells that are coloured red across the entire spreadsheet (i.e. across all sheet tabs)? Ideally with a reference to the first cell it finds that is red.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First, you may not want to do this. Checking the status of every other cell when you make an edit will create a significant amount of lag.

If you do want to do this though you could loop through the spreadsheet by row/column and use the getFontColor() function to determine if the cell contents are red.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontColor()

Something like the following:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
var redCell;
for (var i = 2; i < lastRow; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < lastColumn; j++) {
  if(sheet.getRange(i, j).getFontColor() == "#ff0000") {
    redCell = sheet.getRange(i,j);
    YOUR CODE HERE
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Checking of the red font doesn't need to happen upon cell edit. It could happen upon sheet opening as a once time thing.

Comment: Even better.  No problem at all, just use the same code above in the onOpen()  function instead of onEdit().